# 'passport.authenticate("google")' - React client doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using passport's Google strategy,
part of the process is the client sending a request to '/google' - and then passport.authenticate should redirect the client to the api of google to choose an user.
However, my react client doesn't redirects itself to this api.

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  })
);
```

```
axios.get(`/google`).then(res => {});
```

There is an error from my browser - maybe it'll help somehow.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=c…-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The requests is being send to the google api but the page (window.location) doesn't changes.

Thank You!

Comment: did you whitelist your domain from you are hitting in the google admin console?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Yes I did, Also this program worked before i started using react (sending requests via 'axios').

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing an `AJAX` call where you need to `redirect`.

What passport does is redirects to the actual external auth provider domain and decrypts/make sense of the access code which is being sent from the external auth provider.

So, when you `ajax` the passport route, it will internally redirect, which we don't want. We want an actual redirection so that user can put username and password in the AUTH Provider's site.

So, basically whenever you redirect to external auth provider, you need to REDIRECT not AJAX. That's why `axios` or `request` will not work. You just need to open the route using `href`, or `window.location.href`.